# html, svg, css how to make mouse event not fire on transparent color

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Is it possible to make a mouse event not fire on transparent color of an image?

I have a big background image and several small images which are shaped in different shapes (for example the shape of a ball). I want to catch mouse events on these small images. The problem is that events fire on the whole rect of an image. I can use image map on the background image but this is not a good idea because the small images will be changing under mouse (sprites).

Comment: Basically no...but without seeing the SVG in question it's hard to comment. You can set hover states on specific **internal** paths etc of the SVG (even wrap them in links) but based on a color....no....and even more NO when using a background image (even SVG).

Comment: Thanks for response. There is no svg actually. I want to create that svg or html :)

Comment: I'd love to disagree with @Paulie_D (although I 10000% agree without an example its impossible to say). That said, you can certainly check the `fill` attribute of an svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a number of things, either the fill of an svg shape, path or rect or also the `opacity` property depending on how you have made the element transparent.

For instance:

```
$('svg rect').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).attr('opacity') != 0){
      $('body').append('hovered element with colour');    
  }
});
```

Here is an example:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/zxLbXO

#### Edit

With more complex images like

http://mobilite.mobi/wp-content/uploads/white-rabbit-wallpapers-9.

You have two options. The (to me, a graphic designer turned web designer) the simpler way would be to create an SVG hit map)
[image]

But a solution that would be far more thorough would be to use HTML5 / JavaScript canvas element which can have all of this stuff included, but will be more complex to initially code.

If you use the words `canvas` `alpha` `hit detection` I'm sure you'll be able to google some great results, such as

#### [Image map by alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228987/image-map-by-alpha-channel)

Comment: It's easy with simple objects. What do you recommend to do with images like this: http://jsfiddle.net/holden321/02pp64ex/

Comment: I saw it. I was out of town and waiting for other responses. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is add classes for those small small shapes. for example

```
<div class="big_back" id="big_back">
<div class="small_shapes" id="shape1">
</div>
<div class="small_shapes" id="shape2">
</div>
<div class="small_shapes" id="shape3">
</div>
</div>
```

and in jquery you can call the method as follow

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".small_shapes").mouseenter(function() {
alert("I enteres shapes");
});
```

});
If this is not what you are looking let me know.